# Inserting tags before lines using wordwrap regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My input is:

```
text1 with n characteres text2 with n characteres text3 with n characteres text4 with n characteres
```

I need this output:

```
<tspan> text1 with n characteres </text>
<tspan> text2 with  n characteres </text>
<tspan> text3 with  n characteres </text>
<tspan> text4 with n characteres</text>
```

I'm using the wordwrap function, but I dont know a way to insert `<tspan>` before all lines break.

```
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {

    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;
    cut = cut || false;

    if (!str) { return str; }

    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

     return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );
}

wordwrap(text) , 24, '</tspan>\n'));
```

Comment: You need that output, but what's the input?

Comment: How about `'<tspan>' + wordwrap(text, 24, '</tspan>\n<tspan>') + '</tspan>';` - [demo](http://jsbin.com/pimocagawo/1/)

Comment: I improved my question. I need apply a tag for each line breaked and not to all input.

Comment: You just have to add logic that determines whether there's been at least one break; if so, wrap the output in a tag, otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: I got it. Thank u, @Ja͢ck! Its solve my trouble.